# Subsemigroup of integers is finite type?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, semigroups

I think every subsemigroup of semi-group $(\mathbb N,+)$  is generated by finite many integers (this is not true for $\mathbb N^2$).  Remind: subsemigroup $=$ subset stable for $+$.
Can you give short proof of reference?
Motivation is finite generasion for semi-group in toric varieties but algebraic geometry is not necessary for to answer my elementary purly algebra question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may already know

**Lemma.** If $a,b\in\Bbb N$, then $a\Bbb N+b\Bbb N$ contains all sufficiently large multiples of $\gcd(a,b)$.

*Proof.* Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$. We know $d=xa+yb$ with $x,y\in\Bbb Z$.
More precisely, we can find such $x,y$ with $0\le x<b$ and $-a<y\le 0$.
Trivially $2ab=ab+ba\in a\Bbb N+b\Bbb N$. If $kd\in a\Bbb N+b\Bbb N$, say $kd=na+mb$, and $kd\ge 2ab$ then we cannot have both $n<b$ and $m<a$. If $m\ge a\ge -y$ then $(k+1)d=(n+x)a+(m+y)b$ shows $(k+1)d\in a\Bbb N+b\Bbb N$. Otherwise, $n\ge b$ and $(k+1)d=(n+x-b)a+(m+y+a)b$ does it. By induction, all multiples of $d$ from $2ab$ on are in $a\Bbb N+b\Bbb N$. (As mentioned in the comments, with a bit more care the bound $2ab$ can be lowered substantially, but we don't need this here) $_\square$

**Corollary 1.** If $A$ is a subsemigroup of $\Bbb N$ and contains almost all all sufficiently large multiples of $a\in\Bbb N$ and all sufficiently large multiples of $b\in\Bbb N$, then it contains all sufficiently large multiples of $\gcd(a,b)$.

*Proof.* 
Assume $ka\in\Bbb N$ for all $k>k_a$ and $kb\in\Bbb N$ for all $k>k_b$. 
Let $p$ be a prime $>\max\{k_a,b\}$ and $q$ a prime $>\max\{k_b,a,p\}$. Then $pa\Bbb N+qb\Bbb N\subseteq A$ and hence all sufficiently large multiples of $\gcd(pa,qb)=\gcd(a,b)$ are in $A$. $_\square$

By induction this immediately generalizes the lemma to

**Corollary 2.** If $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\Bbb N$ then $a_1\Bbb N+\ldots +a_n\Bbb N$ contains all sufficiently large multiples of $\gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$. $_\square$

Now let $A$ be a subsemigroup of $\Bbb N$.
Let $d$ be the $\gcd$ of all elements of $A$.
Then we can find finitely many elements $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ of $A$ with $\gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=d$. 
By the above, we know that all sufficiently large multiples of $d$ are in the subsemigroup generatd by $a_1,\ldots,a_n$. Add the finitely many elements of $A$ below that threshold to see that $A$ is finitely generated.

**Edit (evgeniamerkulova).** For dummies like me who had difficulty, notice that from 2nd line of proof of lemma starting with If $kd\in a\Bbb N+b\Bbb N$...Hagen is proving implication $kd\in a\Bbb N+b\Bbb N\implies (k+1)d\in a\Bbb N+b\Bbb N$

Comment: Hagen, this is wonderful answer (and no "I may not already know"). I noticed already that you are much, much stronger than most professional mathamaticians I have meeted. Why did you not become mathematics researcher  ( profile says "you are out of busyness") ?  All my grattitude to you.

Comment: Please everybody vote up !!

Comment: There is a Q that pops up in contests :  If  $x,y$  are distinct co-prime positive integers, show that the smallest positive integer $ n$   that is not equal to  $ax+by$  for some non-negative integers $ a,b$ ,  is $ n=xy-x-y.$

Comment: @user254665 What you write is completely false : try $x=7, y=8$

Comment: yes i meant greatest not smallest.And should also say that  min (x,y)>1.